# C#8 what does "default!" do on generic types?

Tags: c#, generics, non-nullable, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Just playing around with C# 8.0 Beta and updating some of my code to use nullable reference types.

I have a node style class for a Trie implementation. Each node has a value of type `T`. The constructor for the root node does not need a value, so I was setting this to `default`.

Here's a short version:

```
public class Trie<T>
{
    public readonly bool caseSensitive;
    public readonly char? letter;
    public readonly Dictionary<char, Trie<T>> children;
    public readonly Trie<T>? parent;
    public readonly int depth;
    public bool completesString;
    public T value;

    public Trie(bool caseSensitive = false)
    {
        this.letter = null;
        this.depth = 0;
        this.parent = null;
        this.children = new Dictionary<char, Trie<T>>();
        this.completesString = false;
        this.caseSensitive = caseSensitive;
        this.value = default;
    }
}
```

if the last line of the ctor is changed to

```
   this.value = default!;
```

as I saw in a different question here, then it compiles just fine. But I don't understand what the `!` is doing here, and it's pretty hard to google, since google seems to ignore punctuation in most cases.

What does `default!` do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54724546/7775908

Comment: @Alexander thank you. I suspected it was something like this :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does null! statement mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54724304/what-does-null-statement-mean)

Comment: Yeah, default! for reference types would be the same as null!.

Answer (score 7):

The nullable reference types use static flow analysis to figure out if you have a possible null value (thus issuing a warning the variable is being assigned a null value).

The ! is used to allow the developer to suppress the warning generated.  Essentially overriding the compiler.

Comment: The accepted term appears to be "Null Forgiveness Operator"

Comment: I have also heard it called the "Damm it Operator" (as in: 'it's not null Damm it!)  (Attribution: Mads Torgersen) This term was probably not 'accepted' by legal...

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't do anything. If you have a look at the IL generated for each method it is the same. "Nullable Reference Types" is that is a compile time warning/error to ensure that developers have explicitly flagged variables as potentially being assigned a null value. If a variable has been assigned a value with the ! flag then the compiler will not warn anytime the variable is de-referenced without checking for null value.

As `T` has no constraints it will emit a warning
[image: Warning]

Warning will be removed if you replace `default` with `default!` which is the equivalent of saying `null!` for reference types which is self-defeating; For value types `default` is never null so it is doubly self-defeating.

Additionally, if you use `GenericClass<T> where T : struct`, `default` will not emit a warning.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestingGround
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class GenericClass<T>
        {
            public T Value;


            public GenericClass()
            {
                Value = default;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var gc = new GenericClass<string>();
            var strLength = gc.Value.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

IL

```
      IL_0008: ldarg.0      // this
      IL_0009: ldflda       !0/*T*/ class TestingGround.Program/GenericClass`1<!0/*T*/>::Value
      IL_000e: initobj      !0/*T*/
```

Comment: Ah, you need .NET Core Preview for the nullable reference types feature. I will install it and update my answer.

Comment: To turn on requires in the csproj, different from what is on the c# lang github page: `<NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>`